# South skip broken migrations

Tags: python, django, django-south

I am using a 3rd party app inside my django application and the older versions of it had a dependancy on the django auth model, but the newer version supports the custom auth model of django 1.5. 
The problem I am having is that when I install the app and migrate app, it breaks on the migration 002 because it is referencing a table that the final version of the app doesn't need, therefore i dont have.
If i turn off south and just do a syncdb everything works fine. But then I will have to do fake migrations for all my other apps. Is there an easy way that I can have either south skip these errors and keep proceeding with the migrations or south just use the models.py to create the schema and then for me to do a fake migration for just that one app?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing this

```
SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES = { 'app_with_broken_migration':'ignore'}
```

then running `syncdb`

then removing the ignore migrations line and running

```
manage.py migrate app_with_broken_migration --fake
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually make a temporary modification to the migration script that fails. Comment out or modify the parts that are not needed, run the migrations, then restore everything to the way it was before.

It's not ideal, and it involves some duplication of work - you have to do the same steps both on dev machine and on the server, but it lets you preserve South support  and work around the failing migration.

Comment: Problem with that is, that i am doing a pip install for this package. and I use Heroku on the production site which just installs everything based on the requirements file. That would make it hard to do this in production...